# Focus not supported in MediaCapture, but it is available in PhotoCamera

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, windows-store-apps

I'm making an application that uses the phone's camera. When I check if the focus is supported, I receive different responses depending on the class:

**MediaCapture:**

```
var _mediaCapture = new MediaCapture();

// _mediaCapture initialization

if (_mediaCapture.VideoDeviceController.FocusControl.Supported) // false
{
    // ...
}

if (_mediaCapture.VideoDeviceController.Focus.Capabilities.Supported) // false
{
    // ...
}
```

**PhotoCamera:**

```
PhotoCamera camera;

// camera initialization

if (camera.IsFocusSupported) // TRUE
{
    // ...
}
```

My cell phone focuses correctly if it uses `PhotoCamera`, but I need to use `MediaCapture`.

Comment: What device (make and model) are you using? What version is the OS and firmware?

Comment: Samsung ATIV S. OS: `8.10.14157.200` Firmware: `2424.15.3.2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is caused by the firmware of my cell phone. I have tested the application on a Lumia and it works.

Answer (score 1):

Try to configure your MediaCapture:

```
    MediaCapture.VideoDeviceController.FocusControl.Configure(new FocusSettings { Mode = FocusMode.Manual, Value = 100, DisableDriverFallback = true });
    await MediaCapture.VideoDeviceController.FocusControl.FocusAsync();
```

Comment: The method `Configure(...)` generates a `System.Exception`. Message: `The request is not supported` I cannot configure `FocusControl` if `MediaCapture` says that focus is not supported.

Answer (score 1):

Although I might be late, I also had a similar problem with a Microsoft Lumia 532 whilst it worked perfectly on a Nokia Lumia 530.

The problem may be due to the Lumia 530 not having support for focus, or something alike ( it could be happening the same to your device ).

I resolved my problem encapsulating the `configure` on a `try{} catch{}` block like this:

```
try {
    mediaCapture.VideoDeviceController.FocusControl.Configure(FocusSettings);
} catch (Exception exception) {
    // Do something with the exception
}
```

I haven't noticed any difference with the image quality, with or without the `FocusSettings`, but that's may be because the way I work with the image.

Answer (score 0):

Try check whether the `FocusMode` is supported by the camera before setting it. Try this:

```
if (_mediaCapture.VideoDeviceController.FocusControl.SupportedFocusModes != null && _mediaCapture.VideoDeviceController.FocusControl.SupportedFocusModes.Contains(FocusMode.Auto))
{
    _mediaCapture.VideoDeviceController.FocusControl.Configure(new FocusSettings { Mode = FocusMode.Auto });
}
```